# Convert UTF 8 stream to UTF 16 encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, utf-16

I get a stream in UTF8 format, But i would like to get it in UTF16 format as i get some unsupported international characters in C#. How do i achieve this

Comment: Which "*unsupported international characters*" did you get  in C#?

Comment: UTF-8 can represent every unicode character, so I'm not sure what changing the represenation to UTF-16 would achieve.

Comment: Could you show us your code? The likelihood is that your stream is not really UTF-8.

Comment: Were you able to represent those international characters in UTF-16?

Answer (score 0):

If you get unsupported international characters the encoding you'd likely want to use is **not** `UTF16` but: `iso-8859-1`

It correctly encodes characters such as: æ, ø, å

So when you declare your `StreamReader` you'd want to setup the encoding to use:

```
var sReader = new StreamReader(hResponse.GetResponseStream,
                               Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Hope this helps.